# Coreplot annotation clipped

Tags: core-plot

My annotations are clipped as one can see on the picture:
[image]

I've set up the custom paddings and set the masksToBorder flag:

```
graph.plotAreaFrame.masksToBorder  = NO;
```

What should I do, not to clip the annotation or how can I get the frame of annotation to move it appropriately?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the annotation to the graph instead of the plot. The plots and any sublayers like annotations are clipped to the plot area.